# In cakePHP what is the best way for a Controller to set up variables that its View will then access?

Tags: cakephp, variables

Newbie question.  I hope no one minds.

In file AccessesController.php

```
class AccessesController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Accesses';
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index() {
       $this->aVariable = 123;
    }
}
```

In file View/Accesses.ctp

```
<h1> You came thru the AccessesController and set
    aVariable to <?php echo $this->aVariable?>, happy?</h1>
```

It does not print 123 there.  It does not know that this->aVariable has been set to 123.

Am I supposed to use those global variables with `Configure::read / Configure::write`?  Or how can the controller and the view access the same variables?
// Accesses.ctp does not know that this->aVariable has been set to 123.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a variable from a Controller to a View:

```
//Controller
$this->set('variableName', $variableValue);

//View
echo $variableName;
```

It's common practice to use [PHP's compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) if you're going to send more than one variable:

```
//Controller
$var1 = 'pizza';
$var2 = 'beer';
$var3 = 'sleep'; //(trying to keep it PG)
$this->set(compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3'));

//View
echo 'The perfect night: ' . $var1 . ' ' . $var2 . ' ' . $var3;
```